# Bash via Platformio on Atom: arrow keys not functioning

Tags: atom-editor, windows-subsystem-for-linux, platformio

I'm using the Windows Subsystem for Linux Bash in Atom via Platformio - and none of the arrow keys work.

There was an ongoing bug in WSL Bash with the arrow keys that should've been fixed, so I opened `system32\bash.exe` to test, and indeed the arrow keys work there; the problem happens only in Atom.

Does anyone know of a workaround/solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've had this problem myself but I haven't found a full solution. It looks like there's a bug lurking upstream.

Until it's patched, here's a list of alternative commands courtesy of [CherryDT in this thread](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10163):

```
Ctrl+P: Previous command (like up arrow)  
Ctrl+N: Next command (like down arrow)  
Ctrl+B: One character backwards (like left arrow)  
Ctrl+F: One character forwards (like right arrow)  
Ctrl+A: Start of line (like home key)  
Ctrl+E: End of line (like end key)  
Ctrl+D: Delete character (like delete key)
```